# How to remove broken links in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore

We've got a Sitecore site where several items have broken links to an old workflow state that is no longer with us. I know that you can remove links when you delete an item, but I'm not seeing an interface to simple remove a broken link on an item, when the missing item is already gone.

What's the best way to remove broken links in this case? Thanks.

Comment: Try to rebuild the link database using the option in control panel

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is Sitecore admin page that allows removing broken links. You can find it here:

> `http://localhost/sitecore/admin/RemoveBrokenLinks.aspx`

You just select the database and execute the action. You can also serialize all items changed during this process.

You may need to change timeout settings in `web.config`:

```xml
<setting name="DefaultSQLTimeout" value="10:00:00" />
<setting name="DataProviderTimeout" value="00:00:00" />
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to sitecore, why would I want to serialize items that were changed?

Comment: If you realize something important is missing after your action, you can deserialize old version of the item from the serialized file.

Answer (score 3):

Sitecore maintains a table named Links in the database specified in the LinkDatabase section of web.config. You can get all broken links in following way:

```
Sitecore.Data.Database db = Sitecore.Context.Database;
Sitecore.Links.LinkDatabase linkDb = Sitecore.Globals.LinkDatabase;
Sitecore.Links.ItemLink[] brokenLinks = linkDb.GetBrokenLinks(db);
```