# Remove broken link related to sitecore datasource

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I had created one Data source 'DS1' with 5 values in it say 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'. I had then used that Data source in templates and created pages. Now I want to remove the value 'C' from Data source. For that i have remove the value from the list of values in 'DS1' but when i checked on pages I found that the link for values 'C' still exists and the guid is displayed there saying not found. When i am creating a new page, it is not showing me the deleted value but the problem is in the case of existing pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe when you removed the "C" you should got a popup telling you that there are some links and options of what you wanna do like remove links, keep ....etc.

Now as you have the broken links check the following solution:

[how-to-remove-broken-links-in-sitecore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725537/how-to-remove-broken-links-in-sitecore)

Comment: Yes, I got the option to remove  links etc. and I had selected link to another item but it has taken a long and became not responding so canceled that action. I had followed this reference link also which you have shared but after performing this it went to error page and the state is as is.

Comment: Also wherever I am accessing the data source linked on any page like PageItem.Fields["DS1"] it is returing all the TargetIDs inside it including the one i have deleted too

Comment: Yes the broken link ID will be returned anyway. can you check logs to see why the suggested solution in the link provided didn't work for you.